# Date display field drupal

Tags: datetime

I have created two content types **A and B**. I have a **Date** field in A which is referred in B. But in B I want to display the **Date** field separately i.e 3 different select list for month, year and day.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Date API module (part of the [Date module](https://www.drupal.org/project/date)), you can do something like this...

```
<?php
$form['payment_expirationDate'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_select',
    '#title' => t('Expiration Date:'),
    '#date_format' => 'm', OR  '#date_format' => 'y',
    '#default_value' => $expirationDate,
    '#date_year_range' => '-1:+10',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#date_label_position' => 'within'
 ); 
?>
```

The date_select type will give you select box form elements for your field. And the #date_format array key allows you to use a PHP date format string to control what select boxes appear and what goes inside them.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229654/creating-date-field-with-only-month-and-year-drupal)